# Cannot Assign NULL to Pointer Using Linked List in Window Form Application In Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I am trying to make a Music Player In Visual studio 2010 using c++.
I am using link list in it for next and previous function. However When I try To Assign NULL to a node, It displays an error.
Here is chunk of code For LinkedList:

```
    public ref class node {
    public:
   // members
   static String ^ str="";
   node  ^ next;
   node  ^ previous;
   int i;
   };
```

Now When I Make next part of node to NULL It shows Error.

```
 node ^ temp = new node();
 temp->next=NULL;
```

Here is Error:
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'player::node ^'

Comment: You are using the C++/CLI language extension, it requires `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is an int, which is not of type "node". You can either cast it `temp->next = (node*)NULL;` or you can use something like `nullptr`, which should work without casting. Take a look at the link below:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr